# How to change a webpage from .html to .php

Tags: php, html

I have made a webpage using .html and I would now like to change it to .php so I can connect it to a database. I have changed the file extension to .php but now it just opens the actual code in the browser as opposed to opening the website. I have googled it but all I can find is stuff about installing .php on a server, when I am just trying to open the file on my device. I am using Microsoft Edge if that matters. What do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP code is not being executed, but the code shows in the browser source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code)

Comment: You cannot use php without a php server installed. Think about what can actually execute PHP code. The browser alone can't really do that because it's on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you have to understand is php is a server side language whereas html is a client side language. As you might already know, html can be directly interpreted by browser but for php, the case is different. You need to have a server installed.
Moving on to your question **How to change html to php!!**, it's simple, just change the extension of the file.
To run the file, use local server. There are many options you can choose from. Personally I find Xampp easy to setup for beginner. It's my personal opinion though.

To sum up, to change html from php, install a localhost or local server to your computer, migrate your files to server's run directory. You can find plenty of tutorials on setting up localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this has cleared up a lot of my confusion and works perfectly

Comment: It was my pleasure helping you out. I am glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to run a PHP file after changing its extension. You need to install xammp or lamp server. In the localhost server, you can view your PHP pages on any browser.

Comment: Not at all. There are many other options than install xammp/lamp.